# How can I create a function so that a cell has a numerical value, but displays text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I'd like to be able to type this equation into the cell, =hideValue("This is an awesome number.", 15) and have the cell display: This is an awesome number.

I've tried changing the number format, but it's not working exactly how I like. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you saying the user types a number in the cell, and if the number matches a certain number the message is displayed in the same cell?  In which case the value of the number is lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the number in the Script, you could just make a script that gets the number based on the string inputted into the cell. Try using this code:

```js
function hideNumber() {
  var ui =   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  var nearNumber = ui.prompt("What is the text?") //set default to 'This is an awesome number.'
  var number = nearNumber.getResponseText
  cell.setValue(number);
  }
```

and use this code to retrieve the number:

```js
function getNumber() {
  if (number === 'This is an awesome number.') {
    var number = 15
    } else if (number === 'This is not an awesome number.') {
        var number 30
    }
  }
```

You can add more numerical values for text, make exceptions for text by replacing `===` for `!=` (that way, it doesn't check for different variable types), and set it to get cell input. Hope this helps!